# ClassNotFoundException when minifyEnabled and shrinkResources are enabled

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cie.app1.model.GroupModel" when I compile the application in release so, enabling minifyEnabled and shrinkResources cause the application to crash.

The exception line is on the line containing app:argType="com.bts.app1.model.GroupModel" in:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/groupInfoFragment"
    android:name="com.cie.app1.ui.fragment.GroupInfoFragment"
    android:label="fragment_group_info"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_group_info">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_groupInfoFragment_to_chatFragment"
        app:destination="@id/chatFragment" />
    <argument
        android:name="groupModel"
        app:argType="com.bts.app1.model.GroupModel" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_groupInfoFragment_to_addUserDialog"
        app:destination="@id/addUserDialog" />
</fragment>
```

read most of the articles online, I've also cleared the cache.
Thanks'

> 2022-02-14 20:32:06.679 15616-15616/com.cie.app1 E/AndroidRuntime:
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.cie.app1, PID: 15616
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cie.app1/com.cie.app1.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51 in
> com.cie.app1:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #51 in
> com.cie.app1:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3564)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3716)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2229)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8034)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51 in com.cie.app1:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #51 in com.cie.app1:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51 in com.cie.app1:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.cie.app1:navigation/nav_graph line 46
> at t0.t.b(:70)
> at t0.j.f0(:1039)
> at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.v0(:150)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a1(:3009)
> at androidx.fragment.app.c0.e(:474)
> at androidx.fragment.app.c0.m(:257)
> at androidx.fragment.app.q.onCreateView(:142)
> at androidx.fragment.app.n.t(:135)
> at androidx.fragment.app.j.H(:292)
> at androidx.fragment.app.j.onCreateView(:271)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.e.A(:706)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.c.setContentView(:195)
> at com.cie.app1.MainActivity.onCreate(:36)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3539)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3716)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2229)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8034)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cie.app1.model.GroupModel
> 2022-02-14 20:32:06.679 15616-15616/com.cie.app1 E/AndroidRuntime:
> at t0.x$l.a(:163)
> at t0.t.d(:165)
> at t0.t.f(:130)
> at t0.t.a(:103)
> at t0.t.a(:114)
> at t0.t.b(:64)
> ... 35 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cie.app1.model.GroupModel
> at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
> at t0.x$l.a(:146)
> ... 40 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cie.app1.model.GroupModel" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.cie.app1-u-xQjagjG4rral9LyOiLRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cie.app1-u-xQjagjG4rral9LyOiLRA==/lib/arm64,
> /system/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> ... 44 more

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding : -keep class com.bts.app1.model.** {*;} in the proguard-rules.pro